# How can I get php errors reported?

Tags: php

Currently installed php version 5.3.10.
It is not reporting any kind of errors like syntax error e.g.

```
<?php
define("variable" , 10);
variable++;
echo variable;
?>
```

This code has an error and browser should display it . But browser window is empty

*Display error* is *off* as I see in the information given by the phpinfo() in column php core.

I want it to be turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to enable it for all your php projects:

edit the `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` by opening a terminal and typing the following:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

search for the line.

```
display_errors = Off
```

and change `Off` to `On`

If you want to enable it for a single website, in your website's `.htaccess` file add the following line:

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

If you edited your `php.ini` file, a restart for apache is required for the settings to take effect, restart it with following line in a terminal.

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Excellent Dan :) small addition: both .htaccess and apache2.conf override the seting that is in php.ini. And if php.ini contains this settings more than once the last one is the active one.